# Why backbone area can not be stub area in OSPF

Tags: ospf

If there is no ASBR used anywhere in topology. Is it safe to make a backbone area as a stub.

Comment: What would this even be?  A stub area propagates a default from the ABR connected to the backbone area while said ABR filters other types of LSA's.  This pretty much by definition can't be the backbone area.  The closest equivalent would be just to propagate a default in area 0 from an ASBR.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to make the backbone area (area 0) a stub area. However, in theory you actually don't need area 0, you could just use a stub area on the whole network. 
But I would recommend to implement area0, and rather use a stub on rest of the network if you prefer.